# Get time of AdColony video ad before shown to user

Tags: android, interstitial, adcolony

I am trying to use the video ads in tight time frames so I need to know the length of the video before it is to be displayed. Is there a way to get the length of the video ad before it is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video Ad's length is generally 30 seconds or less. Check the blog link for reasoning. https://www.adcolony.com/blog/2014/04/24/713-2/

Currently there is no API available to get this information. Can you please provide us a usecase on support@adcolony.com ?